# Android: Can't set TextView value in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

so I started using fragments today and I am trying to set TextView values on fragment opening. Values can be changed so I packed it all into 1 function so it can be called to update data.
Here:

```
public void loadDetails(){
    ShortcutFunc sf = new ShortcutFunc(this.getActivity());
    ConversePrefs cp = new ConversePrefs(this.getActivity());
    sf.setTextValue(getActivity(), R.id.profile_name, cp.GetStringSetting("name", "unset") + " " + cp.GetStringSetting("surname", "unset"));
    String dob = cp.GetStringSetting("dob", "unset");
    String bod[] = dob.split("\\-");

    LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate (Integer.valueOf(bod[2]), Integer.valueOf(bod[1]), Integer.valueOf(bod[0]));
    LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
    Years age = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, now);
    sf.setTextValue(getActivity(), R.id.profile_bd, dob + " (" + String.valueOf(age) + ")");
    sf.setTextValue(this.getActivity(), R.id.profile_country, cp.GetStringSetting("country", "unset").toString());
    sf.setTextValue(this.getActivity(), R.id.profile_email, cp.GetStringSetting("email", "unset").toString());

    String joined[] = cp.GetStringSetting("join", "unset").split("\\s+");
    String joinedArray[] = joined[0].split("\\-");

    LocalDate joindate = new LocalDate(Integer.valueOf(joinedArray[0]), Integer.valueOf(joinedArray[1]), Integer.valueOf(joinedArray[2]));
    LocalDate today = new LocalDate();
    //Years joinedThen = Years.yearsBetween(joindate, today);
    Days joinedThen = Days.daysBetween(joindate, today);

    sf.setTextValue(this.getActivity(), R.id.profile_join, joined[0] + " (" + joinedThen.toString() + " Days)");
    sf.setTextValue(this.getActivity(), R.id.profile_user, cp.GetStringSetting("username", "unset").toString());
}
```

ShortcutFunc contains this function:

```
public void setTextValue(Activity act, int id, String text){
    TextView tv = (TextView)act.findViewById(id);
    tv.setText(text);
}
```

I use it to save time and set TextViews without doing all that declare etc..
I get NullPointerException on tv.setText(text) the ShortcutFunc function.

This is how I call loadDetails():

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadDetails();
    }
```

So what's wrong?

Comment: Did you oveerride `onCreateView()` for the fragment? If so, then you should not be calling `findViewById(...)` on the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These TextViews are members of your `Fragment` not the `Activity` that is holding the `Fragment`. You should initialize them from the view that you inflated for you fragment in the`OnCreateView()` method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
        return view;
}
```

Comment: But that is the fragment.

Comment: you are calling the activity.findViewByID() you should call that from the view that you inflated for you fragment.